# Why "Домарощинер" is translated as as Hausbotcher?

Tags: перевод

I am reading *[Улитка на cклоне](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5)*, and one of the characters is called **Домарощинер**. In Alan Meyers' English translation, he is called **hausbotcher**. I see how one gets "Haus" from "Дом", but where is "botcher" coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Домарощинер*** is a variation of a Russian adjective ***доморощенный*** (literally grown-at-home).  The latter means self-made, but crude and unprofessional.

If one starts with ***botched-at-home***, then he can arrive at ***Hausbotcher*** after a few modifications.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132901/discussion-on-answer-by-vitaly-why--is-translated-as-as-hausbotcher).